# ask github or sourcetree to ignore moved lines?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac, atlassian-sourcetree, file-diffs

I'm using Git to keep track of the changes I make to my project. I often move entire sections around within my files.

When I view diffs using Sourcetree and GitHub for OSX, it shows me those moved lines as deleted (and shows them as new lines elsewhere). This is confusing visually.

How do I instruct Sourcetree or GitHub to ignore moved lines, and only show lines as deleted if they are truly gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

If you don't like default diffs calculated by git, you can try to use `--patience` (Generate a diff using the "patience diff" algorithm.) and `--histogram` (Generate a diff using the "histogram diff" algorithm.) options of [git diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).

Also this might help [Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files) see Diffing Binary Files.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use --patience in conjunction with Sourcetree or Github for OSX?

Comment: If patience is your choice then you could set it as config `git config --global diff.algorithm patience`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the command line. You can instruct git to try and guess when lines of code have been moved

```
git blame -M -w <file>
```

should show you the author and sha1's of what it thinks are the original authors of those lines. It's an educated guess, so it might be wrong sometimes.